# How to add a sitemap.xml in Nextjs

Tags: node.js, seo, next.js, robots.txt, xml-sitemap

I tried this post [XML sitemap for Nextjs](https://kaloraat.com/articles/xml-sitemap-for-next-js) but it didn't help me out.

How to create a sitemap and robots.txt dynamically add it to nextjs project is my question.
I have built a blog using nextjs and mongodb and express js.
This is my project structure frontend(nextjs)

```
--.next
-- components
-- node_modules
-- pages
-- static
-- config.js
-- next.config.js
-- package.json
-- package-lock.json
```

Comment: You could take the approached mentioned in [Generating a dynamic /robots.txt file in a Next.js app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67398847/1870780) for both sitemap and robots.txt - API route with rewrite.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an express route inside your server.js:

```
const sitemapString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n' +
    '<urlset\n' +
    // ...
    '</urlset>';

expressServer.get( "/sitemap.xml", function( req, res ){
    res.end( sitemapString );
});
```

Or create a file `/pages/sitemap.xml.ts`:

```
// -- dummy exported default, if necessary
export default function Dummy(props){
    return null;
};

export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
    const { res } = context;
    const sitemapString = createSitemap();

    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
    res.write(sitemapString);
    res.end();

    return {
        props: {},
    };
};
```

Or you can create the `sitemap.xml` statically and put it into the `/public` folder.

Comment: In new Next.js versions (12 / 13) it is also possible to add a ["middleware"](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware), and serve the sitemap from there.