# Generating a dynamic /robots.txt file in a Next.js app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, robots.txt

I need a way to answer dynamically to the `/robots.txt` request.

And that's why I've decided to go with `getServerSideProps`

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering

> If you export an async function called getServerSideProps from a page, Next.js will pre-render this page on each request using the data returned by getServerSideProps.

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  return {
    props: {}, // will be passed to the page component as props
  }
}
```

Inside the `context` parameter we have the `req` and `res` objects.

[image]

The response for the `robots.txt` will depend on the `req.headers.host` value.

For example:

- `www.mydomain.com` should render a production `robots.txt` file
- `test.mydomain.com` should render a test `robots.txt` file (that I'll use on test/staging deployments).

This is my current code:

**pages/robots.txt.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { GetServerSideProps } from "next";

interface Robots {
  ENV: "TEST" | "PROD"
}

export const getServerSideProps : GetServerSideProps<Robots> = async (context) => {
  const { req, res } = context;
  const { host } = req.headers;

  res.write("XXX");
  res.end();

  return({                // This is unnecessary (but Next.js requires it to be here)
    props: {
      ENV: "TEST"
    }
  });
};

const Robots: React.FC<Robots> = (props) => {  // This is also unnecessary (but Next.js requires it to be here)
  console.log("Rendering Robots...");

  return(
    <div>
      I am Robots 
    </div>
  );
};

export default Robots;  // This is also unnecessary (but Next.js requires it to be here).
```

It seems to be working:

[image]

But the weird part is that `Next.js` demands me to export a component from that page. And also returns a `props: {}` object from `getServerSideProps` is also required.

What is the way to go here? I'm basically using `req,res` from `getServerSideProps` to returning something that is not a page. Is this an anti-pattern?

**UPDATE**

Yes, this is an anti-pattern. You should use `rewrites`. See the selected answer.

Comment: Have you considered using an [API route](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction) instead? And have a [rewrite](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) map `/robots.txt` requests to `/api/robots`.

Comment: @juliomalves I've thought about that. But I don't know how would Google handle that redirect to `api/robots`. What do you think?

Comment: The rewrite would happen in Next.js so it'd essentially be the same as if you had an actual page for it.

Comment: @juliomalves I'll test that tomorrow and let you know! Thanks

Comment: @juliomalves works flawlessly. Exactly what I needed. Feel free to write an answer. That is definitely the recommended approach. Thanks

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use an [API route](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction) instead for the logic and have a [rewrite](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) map `/robots.txt` requests to `/api/robots` in your Next.js config file.

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
    // ...
    async rewrites() {
        return [
            {
                source: '/robots.txt',
                destination: '/api/robots'
            }
        ];
    }
}
```

```js
// /pages/api/robots
export default function handler(req, res) {
    res.send('XXX'); // Send your `robots.txt content here
}
```

Comment: Can someone say more about why OP's solution of getServerSideProps is an anti-pattern? Wouldn't using the API not take advantage of next's static build caching?

Comment: @JackRatner OP expressly mentioned _"I need a way to answer dynamically to the `/robots.txt` request"_ meaning the robots file should be created dynamically upon request. Statically caching it would lose the dynamic aspect of it.

Comment: @JackRatner _"why OP's solution of getServerSideProps is an anti-pattern?"_ - I wouldn't necessarily call it an _anti-pattern_. While `getServerSideProps` _could_ be used to generate these kind of files, that's not the proper use-case for it. `getServerSideProps` is supposed to be used in `page` components, to allow those pages to be server-side rendered. Using an API route to generate dynamic `robots.txt` or `sitemap.xml` files is more idiomatic.

Comment: But even Next.js is using ```getServerSideProps``` in their Sitemaps example: https://nextjs.org/learn/seo/crawling-and-indexing/xml-sitemaps

Comment: @VeljkoBlagojevic It's certainly possible, and you could use `getServerSideProps` for that purpose. I still believe using an API route makes more sense.

Comment: Many thanks I combined this with https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/15453#discussioncomment-987749 gave me the perfect solution